# "Unable to generate an IRI for the item" with uuid

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

i change id generator to uuid generation like that :

```
`
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
#[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
#[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
private ?Uuid $id = null;`
```

`private Uuid $id;

```
public function getId(): Uuid
{
    return $this->id;
}
`
```

but when i create/get or with other methods i get this error :
`Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\MyEntity\"`

My endpoints look like this :

```
    #[GetCollection(
    uriTemplate: '/bankroll',
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['bankroll:list:view']],
    provider: BankrollStateProvider::class
)]
#[Post(
    uriTemplate: '/bankroll',
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['bankroll:add']],
    processor: BankrollStateProcessor::class
)]
#[Get(
    uriTemplate: '/bankroll/{id<\d+>}',
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['bankroll:view']],
    security: 'object.owner == user',
    write: false,
)]
#[Put(
    uriTemplate: '/bankroll/{id<\d+>}',
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['bankroll:edit']]
)]
#[Delete(
    uriTemplate: '/bankroll/{id<\d+>}'
)]
```

Comment: I found, this error occured by the {id<\d+>} in iriTemplate. I replace it with {id<'. Requirement::UUID .'>

Comment: thank for your answer